# DataGrid show an empty row when DataTable is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have a `DataGrid` (**dg1**) that binds to a `DataTable` (**DataSet.Tables**). 
The code runs fine and `DataGrid` is showing the Data in `DataTable` correctly.

But, if I `Clear()` the `DataTable`, the `DataGrid` is also clear but left with one single empty row, which I don't know how to get rid of.  I have already cleared the DataTable. Where is this empty row come from?

```
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();

string sqlStr = @"SELECT * FROM FooTable";
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sqlStr, conn);

da.Fill(ds, "FooTable");

/* get data table reference */
dt = ds.Tables["FooTable"];

DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
newRow["FooName"] = "Donkey";
dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

dg1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dt.Clear();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you set the allowaddrow property of the datagrid to false?

Comment: @Jonathan, I set it to false. Still persist the empty row. Strange. Btw, how does allowdrop has anything to do with it..?

Comment: He said AllowAddRow, not AllowDrop...

Comment: there is no AllowAddRow method in DataGrid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That row normally is the NewItemPlaceholder which is used to create new items in the bound collection. You should try setting [`CanUserAddRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows.aspx) to `false`.

Comment: H.B. is right just call this.mydatagridctrl.CanUserAddRows=false; i your codebehind (after InitializeComponent();)

Answer (score 1):

The empty row that is shown is probably due to the reason that by default in datagrid, empty row is there in the last so that the user can add new row.
try doing
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

Answer (score 0):

@Abdul Muqtadir : Correct explanation.

The below code will do what you are looking for:

```
   dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
```

for Datagrid you should set DataGrid.CanUserAddRows to false;