# XamDataGrid show an empty row when Collection is empty

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, infragistics, xamdatagrid

![enter image description here][1]I have a XamDataGrid that binds to a Collection. The code runs fine and XamDataGrid is showing the Data when collection is having data.

But, if I Clear() the collection and assign to the datasource, the XamDataGrid is also clear but left with one single empty row, which I don't know how to get rid of. I have cleared the collection. Where the empty row come from?

Using Infragistics 10.2

![Highlighted is the empty record][1]

Comment: can you give us maybe a screenshot? is this maybe the filter row? which version of infragistics do you have?

Comment: not able to add screenshot.

Comment: Please refer to the screenshot there in below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815858/datagrid-show-an-empty-row-when-datatable-is-empty

Comment: with 12.2 all works fine, if i set a ObservableCollection to the grid and clear the collection, the grid doesn't show an empty row...

Comment: Okay. Will try with the latest version

Comment: I have tried with latest 14.2 version but the issue still occurs

Answer (score 0):

In the native `DataGrid` one empty row shown if property `DataGrid.CanUserAddRows == true`

when you click at that row new element add to source collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DataSet and having the DataTable with empty rows, first get the DataView from the DataSet

Then you have to assign the DataSource to xamDataGrid like below xamDataGrid.DataSource = dataView;